# phpmyadmin in XAMPP is not working mac OS BigSur

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am new to php. I was already running mysql ver 8.0.27 on my mac 11.5 (BigSur)
Now i have installed XAMPP (8.0.15), Apache is running perfectly but MySQL Database is stopped and also localhost/phpmyadmin is not working. But my previously installed mysql is running, i am using it through workbench. Can i use my running mysql with it or need to change the port to run from XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use modern dev stacks like Docker or Vagrant (I prefer docker) ... XAMPP is outdated. But it looks like a port problem. If you really want to use XAMPP, try changing the port numbers.

Also take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXWQTpSHIMc&ab_channel=BINARYHACK

Comment: Thanks Patrick but i'd like to go with XAMPP

Comment: DONE !! Port was the issue I have change it and it's working , Thank You